# Adding Zurb Foundation to a new asp.net webforms app

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms, zurb-foundation

Can someone please tell me the proper way to add Zurb Foundation 5 CSS Framework to a new ASP.NET Application that is using the Webforms template and No Authentication.

I would like to follow all of the conventions that microsoft put in place in this template such as bundles.

I have attempted to do this and I keep getting errors in the js console.

Here are the steps I took:

1. Add new Webforms application, No authentication.
2. Remove bootstrap completely from site.
3. Download Zurb Foundation 5 (default) from their website.
4. Add css and img folders over to the Content folder.
5. Add js/foundation and js/vendors folders to the Scripts folder.
6. Add a new StyleBundle to the Bundle.config that includes Content/css/foundation.min.css and Content/css/normalize.css
7. In the master page add the line `Styles.Render("~/bundles/foundationCss")` within the placeholder tags to register the style bundle

Answer (score 1):

This is what i do. My demo is very simple, i'm not using masterpage [image: I just add the folders and two files]